Would you prefer to break a line after a preposition or an article, or would you choose to hyphenate a word instead?
I find that when a line of text ends with an article or a preposition, it disrupts my reading. However, this issue seems lesser when a word is hyphenated. Do you share this experience? Do you have any resources on this?
For example, I am referring to choosing between "the / demonstration" and "the demon- / stration."

Depends upon the break.
I try and avoid hyphenation which results in full words. Full incongruent words can often be more disruptive than the hyphenation itself.
"demon-stration" would be an unsatisfactory break for me. I'd much prefer "dem-onstration" or "demonst-ration"
Really, this is only an issue for full justification, which I also tend to avoid. Ragged right is easier for humans to read. (related article)
And, no paragraph should ever end in a partial orphan such as "stration." The paragraph should be adjusted or edited to remove the orphan, or to add more words to the last line so there is no orphan.

"Ragged right is easier for humans to read." do you have any evidence for this claim?

https://www.myfonts.com/pages/fontscom-learning-fontology-level-2-making-type-choices-justified-vs-rag-right -- personally, justified type appears like a shortcut in many instances. Not always, when it's done with care. But often it's done just so someone doesn't have to worry about spacing and gets solid boxes that don't necessarily look like text. There's a use for justified type, but it can be overused.

Also: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/145517/how-does-unobviously-uneven-spaces-between-words-in-justified-text-affect-readin

It's interesting that you often advocate for splitting text in "annoying" places. To lead the reader onwards. Also when it comes to paragraphs where I remember you talked about always splitting them in the middle. I totally follow the idea. I just often struggle with clients who wants the opposite. They want compound words (we have a lot of those in Danish as we can make them up as we please) hyphenated in it's logical parts and they want paragraphs, sections and subheadings to start in the top of columns/pages. I try to enforce my own philosophy but often have to give in.

The nature of the piece matters. I am often referring to more sales-oriented text, which is generally what I'm using.

The tradition for headlines on news and magazine articles was to not use hyphenation at all and to not split phrases, including infinitives -- not doing so results in what we called "bad breaks." In justified text, people generally just go with the machine hyphenation.
